# What is the difference between two methods? (I think it is simple but I don't know)

Tags: c#, properties

I don't know the difference between these two lines of code:

```
public int method1 { get {return 1;} }
public int method2 {return 1}
```

What is the difference between `method1` and `method2`? I think the result would be the same, but what reason would I use the second one (`method2`)?

Comment: First is a property, not a method (it is method internally). Second gives an error - you should add `()`.

Comment: The second line does not even compile. Please post a [mcve] in the future to save us the guesswork of what your question might have been, had it actually compiled.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you've tried to declare a *property*:

```
public int method1 { get {return 1;} }
```

and a *method*:

```
// please, notice required ()
public int method2() {return 1;}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first is not a method, it's a read-only property that returns an `int`.  The second is a method that returns an int, although your syntax is not quite correct:

```
public int method2() {return 1;} // <-- note parens and semicolon added.
```

I would advise googling methods and properties in C#.